# App notifications for a web app

Tags: web-applications, mobile

I am a programmer with some experience in building PHP web apps.

My latest idea is to build a web app in Laravel which would let driver-users register the route they are going to take when going from one city to another. Each route will be comprised of cities and towns through which the driver will go through/by. Also, passenger-users will be able to register their interest for a route with a desired start and destination point.

A crucial feature of this project is the notification service. How could I create a mobile app that would provide users with the web app's functionality + notify about:

1. new passenger application
2. confirm/decline application
3. match of a route created by a passenger with a new route created by a driver

keeping duplication of code in both apps at minimum?

Comment: Consider cross-platform frameworks that run everywhere (write most of the code in JS). If you're Android-only, you can share Kotlin (or even Scala) much of the code between server and both clients. With iOS, you could at least share Swift code between mobile client and server.

Answer (score 0):

I would not make a native app but instead only a webapp that also is the mobile app. That way I could share JS/HTML/CSS between all platforms and keep a server backend for communication between devices.

This way I would choose a web framework (JS/HTML/CSS) to make the mobile app and not make a native mobile app (Swift, Java, C++...).

Comment: Yeah, I also had such an idea. But would it be possible to implement notifications in an app developed in such a framework. If so, could you recommend some frameworks fit for this purpose?